# TypeError: Cannot call method '$on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my controller.js code in angular app

```
function MyCtrl1($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?");
    if (answer) {
      $location.url($location.url(next).hash());
      $rootScope.$apply();
    }
  });
}
MyCtrl1.$inject = [];


function MyCtrl2() {}
MyCtrl2.$inject = [];
```

When i checked in chrome i got the following error in developer console

```
TypeError: Cannot call method '$on' of undefined
```

can any one point out what may be wrong.

Comment: Try `console.log($scope)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject $scope.

```
MyCtrl1.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

**EDIT: The full fix...**

Anything you're passing into your controller, you're going to need to inject, if you're injecting explicitly with `ctrl.$inject = [];`

```
function MyCtrl1($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
  $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")){
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
MyCtrl1.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope'];
```

Comment: that did the trick but now getting another error  ReferenceError: $location is not defined

Comment: You also need to inject $location, which is another service.

Comment: Added a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: getting one more new error this time Error: $digest already in progress

Comment: Oops... the $apply() wasn't necessary.

Comment: but the url doesn't change when i press OK in confirm

Comment: Seems like this question is really a lot more than one question. lol

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're attempting to do here. I can tell you that `$location.url(next).hash()` isn't valid. Have you looked at this in a debugger? Like in Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: I've changed the answer again. I've not used locationChangeStart before and it's currently undocumented, so I'm not going to be much more help.

Comment: thnks but u solved the error stated in question.So marking as answer